# JQuery Cycle 2 Slide exibindo abaixo do alinhamento

Tags: jquery, cycle2

Estou usando o plugin `Cycle 2` do `JQuery`.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eis o link: http://www.dinamicaimoveis.com.br/novo/

Tenho duas div's. Uma flutuando à esquerda e outra à direita. 
Em uma tenho um texto e uma imagem.
Na outra, tenho um slideshow.

A `div` do `Slide` show `flutua` à `direita`. Acontece que acima do `slideshow` existe um espaço até o topo de uns `20px` que não consigo tirar, fazendo com que ela fique esses `20px` abaixo do alinhamento da `div` que `flutua` á `esquerda`.

Na verdade o que parece mesmo é que além da área qe se vê o slide show, existe algum elemento invisivel mas que esta ali ocupando espaço.

Eis o código:

```
<div class="dados">
  <?php echo $constantes->getCorretor(); ?> - <?php echo $constantes->getCreci(); ?><br />
  <img src="_img/icon-caixa.gif" /><br />
  <?php echo $constantes->getEnderecoCompletoSite(); ?><br />    
</div>


<div class="cycle-slideshow slide" 
    data-cycle-fx=fadeout
    data-cycle-timeout=3000
    data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true"
    data-cycle-slides="div.slide"
    >
    <!-- prev/next links -->
    <div class="cycle-prev"></div>
    <div class="cycle-next"></div>
    <div class="cycle-pager"></div>

    <div class=slide>
       <img src="_img/_banner/muriae.png">
        <div class=cycle-overlay>Brazão Muriaé</div>
    </div>

    <div class=slide>
       <img src="_img/_banner/grande_hotel.jpg">
        <div class=cycle-overlay>Grande Hotel Muriaé</div>
    </div>

    <div class=slide>
       <img src="_img/_banner/cristo.jpg">
        <div class=cycle-overlay>Cristo Redentor Muriaé</div>
    </div>

    <div class=slide>
       <img src="_img/_banner/matriz_centro.jpg">
        <div class=cycle-overlay>Matriz São Paulo</div>
    </div>

    <div class=slide>
       <img src="_img/_banner/matriz_porto.jpg">
        <div class=cycle-overlay>Matriz do Porto</div>
    </div>

    <div class=slide>
       <img src="_img/_banner/matriz_barra.jpg">
        <div class=cycle-overlay>Matriz da Barra</div>
    </div>

    <div class=slide>
       <img src="_img/_banner/matriz_barra2.jpg">
        <div class=cycle-overlay>Matriz da Barra</div>
    </div>

    <div class=slide>
       <img src="_img/_banner/pedra.jpg">
        <div class=cycle-overlay>Pedra Santa Maria</div>
    </div>

    <div class=slide>
       <img src="_img/_banner/rodoviaria.jpg">
        <div class=cycle-overlay>Prefeitrura e Rodoviária</div>
    </div>

    <div class=slide>
       <img src="_img/_banner/cachoeira.jpg">
        <div class=cycle-overlay>Cachoeira do Rio Preto</div>
    </div>

    <div class=slide>
       <img src="_img/_banner/horto.jpg">
        <div class=cycle-overlay>Horto Florestal</div>
    </div>

    <div class=slide>
       <img src="_img/_banner/panaroma1.jpg">
        <div class=cycle-overlay>Vista Pnarâmica</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvdo: No css do plugin havia um border 10px auto